# Spring rest endpoint not returning body

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am very confused about the behavior of one of my rest endpoint int my Spring application

I have a simple controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("HELOOOO");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

And I am sending requests to this endpoint. The request is accepted and returns `200 OK` but the body is missing. I see the printline and I see the request being successfully processed in my browser console but there is no body.

I have other endpoints in my application (some even in the same controller class) which work fine so I am confused what might be the reason for this particular one.

EDIT: this is what I am seeing in the web console:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 08:37:46 GMT

Failed to load response data
```

`@ResponseBody` annotation does nothing.

EDIT2: Thank you all for your suggestion - especially the one about trying the endpoint with `cUrl`. The exception was not in Spring but in my client handling the response where I was handling it incorrectly.

Comment: try @ResponseBody annotation.

Comment: @Jabongg that's the default when using RestController.

Comment: How do you determine that there is no body?

Comment: What happens when you execute `curl http://localhost:8080/test`?

Comment: I tried with simple Strings and also with objects. Nothing works and I am very confused since all my other endpoints work normally and look the same.

Comment: check your imports

Comment: curl works, interesting... so there is some problem with my browser?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not sure what you mean by "web console", don't know how you sent the request from your browser and how you got that output.

Comment: Problem in code unrelated to the question

Comment: Works fine for me, I removed function argument `Principal principal`. `curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/test"` using Latest Spring-boot version

Comment: I hope you understand the actually issue here. Your browser tried to parse `hello` as JSON, but it's not a valid JSON formatted string. However, if you returned `"hello"` literarily your browser should be able to parse it.

Comment: @Smajl tip for the future: when you really want to know, from the browser, what a response contains, don't rely on your JavaScript code to show it. Open the browser dev tools, go to the network panel, and click on the request to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a ResponseEntity as following:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity test(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("HELOOOO");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("hello", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Response status is an `200`, but response ultimately comes with an error message `"Failed to load response data"`.

*This could only be due to failure to serialise the data you returned to a valid JSON.*

I'm not a Spring expert, but perhaps if you returned `"\"hello\""` it should be fine.

[image]